# Javascript promise returns undefined in switch statement

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this question has been solved before, I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315450/promise-returns-undefined), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it), too (which, I thought, was a good lead, but I failed to understand the accepted answer) and lastly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185880/making-a-promise-work-inside-a-javascript-switch-case) one.

I have this case in a switch statement:

```
function setFieldTransformation(iteration) {

    //Omitting first hundred lines and switch declaration...
    case "customer.subscriptionSet":

        var subscriptionCode;

        if (iteration.oldValue && iteration.newValue) {

            if (Array.isArray(iteration.oldValue) && Array.isArray(iteration.newValue)) {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.oldValue[0].service;
            } else {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.oldValue.service;
            }
        } else if (iteration.oldValue) {
            if (Array.isArray(iteration.oldValue)) {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.oldValue[0].service;
            } else {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.oldValue.service;
            }
        } else {
            if (Array.isArray(iteration.newValue)) {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.newValue[0].service;
            } else {
                subscriptionCode = iteration.newValue.service;
            }
        }

        return getSubscriptionName(subscriptionCode);
        break;
}
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Here I check for a subscription code, then I call this function:

```
    function getSubscriptionName(subscriptionCode) {
        ServiceService.getService(subscriptionCode)
          .then(function(response){
             var subscriptionName = response.data.name
             return response.data.name;
        })
    }
```

Which calls a service to get the subscription name. That string is then passed through this function and printed in a table:

```
function transformDetailValuesReworked(iteration) {
    //...
    var fieldSetTransformation = setFieldTransformation(iteration);
    return fieldSetTransformation;
}
```

**What actually happens:**

If I understand correctly the asynchronous nature of the promises, `var subscriptionName = response.data.name` could never happen, so the return is `undefined`.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried a chained promise approach, but it does not behave the way I expect. Also, and even though it is not a good practice, I've tried to set up callbacks in the functions, but ultimately ending up in the same dead spot.

I'm pretty sure I can use an [async function approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), but I'm concerned about compatibility issues.

Could you shed some light? Thank you.

Comment: `getSubscriptionName` needs a `return`

Comment: `getSubscriptionName` doesn't return anything. You need to `return ServiceService.getService(...)`, which makes it return a promise, and then you need to chain that promise in `transformDetailValuesReworked` with `setFieldTransformation(iteration).then(function (fieldSetTransformation) { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

You've simply forgotten to return anything from `getSubscriptionName`

```
function getSubscriptionName(subscriptionCode) {
        return ServiceService.getService(subscriptionCode)
          .then(function(response){
             var subscriptionName = response.data.name
             return response.data.name;
        })
    }
```

But then your next method needs to treat it as async too

```
function transformDetailValuesReworked(iteration) {
    //...
    var fieldSetTransformation = setFieldTransformation(iteration);
    return fieldSetTransformation; // This is a promise not a value!
}
```

Comment: Given how the function is used in `transformDetailValuesReworked`, I don't think they forgot so much as *not understood* how promises work…

Comment: @deceze I got that too - updated but the dupe is the right one!

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the answers. I'm trying the Promise object approach: `function getSubscriptionName(subscriptionCode) { var subscriptionName; return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ ServiceService.getService(subscriptionCode) }); }`, however this is not working. What I'm missing?

Comment: @wickedchild you dont need to do that at all - just add the return statement as per my answer. But in answer to that direct comment - you're not `resolve`ing the promise.